# Core Data freezes app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to add core data to iOS app. The problem is, when i try to get ManagedObjectContext it freezes.
Here's my stack:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "test" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Model", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

it is in AppDelegate. 
Here is code:

```
var appDel : AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate);
        var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        var newLine = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Track", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newLine.setValue("test123", forKey: "name")
        newLine.setValue(String(points[points.count-2].x) + ";"+String(points[points.count-2].y), forKey: "start")
                    newLine.setValue(String(points[points.count-1].x) + ";"+String(points[points.count-1].y), forKey: "end")


            do {try context.save()}

        catch{}
```

it freezes on the second line. I copy pasted stack from another project, that probably can be the reason. After initializing, all fields of appDel are nil, but i guess it's ok because of lazy variables.

Comment: Did you add the .xcdatamodel file in your project ? its better that you should create a new project with coredata model and add the coredata stack from the newly created project

Comment: yes, i have .xcdatamodel file and i did just as you wrote

Comment: it freezes on this line ?  var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

Comment: Then you would have to add breakpoints on all your coreData Stack Methods because they are called when you try to access NSManagedobjectContext first time

Comment: When your app freezes, tap the pause button in xcode, and see on which line in your stack setup code your app got stuck.

Comment: When i add a breakpoint near appDel - i never run it without breakpoint - it stucks at 
`libsystem_kernel.dylib semaphore_wait_trap:
    0x1110e7fa4 <+0>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x1110e7fa7 <+3>:  movl   $0x1000024, %eax          ; imm = 0x1000024 
    0x1110e7fac <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1110e7fae <+10>: req`

When i run it without any breakpoints or add them to stack declaration, it works fine, i even checked .sqlite file. Anyone experienced same problem?